# React Router v6: How to organize routes for handling multiple params when the param is first in the path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am running into a scenario where I need to place parameters at the front of the path but am running into a problem using v6.

Suppose I have the following routing:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path='/:companyslug'>
        <Route path='home'/>
        <Route path='about'/>
        <Route path='profile/:id'/>
    </Route>
    <Route path='/:companyslug/:departmentslug'>
        <Route path='home'/>
        <Route path='about'/>
        <Route path='profile/:id'/>
    </Route>
</Routes>
```

When I try this for example on the following url, https://www.anydomain.com/company1/home, it keeps getting picked up by the /:company/:department route when I need it to be picked up by the /:company route.  Is there a specific ordering or other v6 technique that will fix this issue?

Comment: I've copy/pasted your code into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-how-to-organize-routes-for-handling-multiple-params-when-the-pa-m9dw89) and the routes match and render as I'd expect them to. Perhaps you have an issue elsewhere? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] that reproduces the issue? Feel free to fork my sandbox and include more of your actual code to see if you can create a demo we could inspect live.

Answer (score -1):

That's because it should be like this:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path='/:companyslug'>
        <Route path='home'/>
        <Route path='about'/>
        <Route path='profile/:id'/>
        <Route path='/:departmentslug'>
            <Route path='home'/>
            <Route path='about'/>
            <Route path='profile/:id'/>
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Routes>
```

You've already defined the `/:companyslug` route. Anything that needs `/:companyslug` shouldn't be redefined at the same level, it should be nested underneath it